# (MS Word/VBA) Executing Mail Merge when document opens

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been trying my Macro for testing but somehow something is not working. I tried recording a Macro and compared the code to mine. The recorded Macro worked. But as soon as I started modifying it, nothing would happen if I run the Macro.

**I have Word Object Library**

Working Macro:

```
Sub DistrictMailMerge()
On Error GoTo NoKTOAccess

ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
RunMMKTO
Exit Sub

NoKTOAccess:
    If Err.Number = 5174 Then
        RunMMPEO
    End If
End Sub



Sub RunMMKTO()
'Wrong Filename for testing purpose'
'-----------------------------------
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
    Name:="\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm2", _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, _
    ReadOnly:=False, _
    LinkToSource:=True, _
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    PasswordDocument:="", _
    PasswordTemplate:="", _
    WritePasswordDocument:="", _
    WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
    Revert:=False, _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry ", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [CR Step 2 - Mail Merge List$] WHERE [ISS No#] LIKE '%-%'", _
    SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
End Sub



Sub RunMMPEO()
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
        "\\192.168.9.190\new_admin\File Sharing\Caseworkers\Herman\ISS OSP\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm" _
        , ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
        WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:= _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry " _
        , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [CR Step 2 - Mail Merge List$] WHERE [ISS No#] LIKE '%-%'", _
        SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
End Sub
```

Macro that does nothing (very rarely error as shown below):

> Error of Run-time error '5852': Requested object is not available

```
Sub DistrictMailMerge()
On Error GoTo NoKTOAccess

ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
RunMMKTO
Exit Sub

NoKTOAccess:
    If Err.Number = 5174 Then
        RunMMPEO
    End If
End Sub


Sub RunMMKTO()
'Wrong Filename for testing purpose'
'-----------------------------------
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
.OpenDataSource _
    Name:="\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm", _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry ", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [CR Step 2 - Mail Merge List$] WHERE [ISS No#] LIKE '%-%'", _
    SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
.Execute
End With
End Sub



Sub RunMMPEO()
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
.OpenDataSource _
    Name:="\\192.168.9.190\new_admin\File Sharing\Caseworkers\Herman\ISS OSP\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm", _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry ", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [CR Step 2 - Mail Merge List$] WHERE [ISS No#] LIKE '%-%'", _
    SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
.Execute
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches to your problem.

1. Find out what your sub `DistricMailMerge` actually does. Put a break point in its first line and press F5. When it hits the stop continue pressing F8 and watch which part of it actually executes.
2. I am not familiar with MailMerge. Therefore I start here:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/mailmerge-object-word. I find that your code is quite different from what MS suggests. I am intrigued by your line `ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument` which seems to specify only that the merge is to be sent to a document without specifying which one, nor how to merge. MS suggested code resolves that issue. 
   Without studying further, I find the question of why one of your two versions actually works much more powerful than the one why the other doesn't.

Comment: Actually I made some changes myself after that and I created another question

The mail merge is working, if I call the Macro manually from the developers tab in the opened Word document

But I have no idea how to execute it from Excel

[Here is the link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207127/running-mail-merge-from-excel-on-an-embedded-docx-word-file)

Comment: I'm glad you are making headway. The problem you describe in your new question isn't the one you describe in your above comment. It seems you wish to start working in Excel. In order to open a Word document and manipulate it from within Excel you need to create an instance of the Word application. It's not difficult. Google for something like "call Word from Excel" and you will find plenty of code.

Comment: Just bear in mind that you are using 2 DLLs. Therefore, when you declare variables you should specify whether they are Word's or Excel's. If you don't declare Excel will presume they are Excel's, and then your Word code won't run.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll dig a bit again before I fire another question