# Running Mail Merge from Excel on an Embedded .docx (Word) file

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge, vba

Please help on figuring this out as I'm stuck at the last stage trying to properly define my variables in the following code.

**I want to execute the following in sequence:**

1. Click the button 'CommandButton1'
2. The Form called 'CR_MMFormTest', which is an embedded document, will then open (mergefields already completed with no datasource pointed at, at the moment)
3. VBA helps me create a replica of the Form, and use that for....
4. Calling the function DistrictMailMerge

**The problem, I encountered, lies on 3, and 4.**

1. The replica script does not work for an embedded document. It would say

> Run-time Error '5174': Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it
>   moved, renamed, or deleted?

2. I'm not able to use the function DistrictMailMerge to recognise that the function should work on the opened document

**What I tried:**
I thought about creating the Document Open event for my embedded documents but it wouldn't work. The documents only open as a temp document and the scripts will not save. So I cannot just execute the DistrictMailMerge function during the open event without using Excel to do it instead.

I believe the issue lies on the nature of these opened documents. They don't really 'exist' in a way a normal Word document would. I wonder if anyone could help me out please.

This is the subroutine:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Resource Bank").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("CR_MMFormTest").Select
Selection.Verb xlVerbOpen


Call DistrictMailMerge

End Sub
```

This is the function I intended for the opened document to call:

```
Function DistrictMailMerge()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo NoKTOAccess

Application.Documents.Add ActiveDocument.FullName
Close_All_Except_Active_Document

RunMMKTO
Exit Function

NoKTOAccess:
    If Err.Number = 5174 Then
        RunMMPEO
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function


Sub Close_All_Except_Active_Document()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim KeepOpen As String
    KeepOpen = ActiveDocument.Name

    For i = Documents.Count To 1 Step -1
      If Documents(i).Name <> KeepOpen Then Documents(i).Close Savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Next i
End Sub


Sub RunMMKTO()
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.OpenDataSource _
    Name:="\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm", _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry ", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [CR Step 2 - Mail Merge List$] WHERE [ISS No#] LIKE '%-%'", _
    SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
End With
End Sub


Sub RunMMPEO()
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.OpenDataSource _
    Name:="\\192.168.9.190\new_admin\File Sharing\Caseworkers\Herman\ISS OSP\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm", _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\Astc-ls-001\new_admin\File Sharing\001. KLN 1\Caseworkers\Herman\Masterlist One-Stop Portal.xlsm;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry ", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [CR Step 2 - Mail Merge List$] WHERE [ISS No#] LIKE '%-%'", _
    SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Still no one....after 2 years